# msiexec opening by itself

Tags: windows-8.1, popups, windows-installer

I just got an issue with msiexec since three days, I don't know why it does that but it just opens a popup that list the available msiexec commands. It does that each 6 hours, something like that.

I have no idea why, what I did or what I installed that could have a link with this issue.

Is there a proper way to solve this issue? I found some discussion about it, but so far the only solution was to disable msiexec and it's a problem because it's used to install software and I would need to enable it each time I want to install new soft or stuff like that.

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Why did someone down voted without saying why? Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Scheduled Tasks. (With Windows 8 search for 'Schedule tasks' and there should be an option to view the Active Tasks)

Alternatively, if you download [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from Sysinternals/Microsoft and run this when msiexec is open, you should be able to see which process has started msiexec and also any parameters that have been passed to msiexec which might give a clue what is causing it.

Comment: I just checked, nothing unusual I guess, I checked the date of the last execution and I found nothing so far. I'll take a look there next time.

Answer (score 0):

By disabling the msiexec you will limit many installers (.msi files) from executing. considering microsoft installer advantages I would not recommend that option.

I think you may have configured some update apps which might be causing this issue. processexplorer will help you in this case as sgmoore has pointed out.
e.g.
[image]

in above image plugin_host.exe is from sublime text. similar way you can find for others

regarding downvotes, I am also curious why would someone downvote this question?